# electronjs - remote access nodejs

Tags: node.js, electron

I have a very basic setup in my `electron.js`. then I have a `js` file that link directly to `index.html`:

**app.js**

```
  const http = require('http');
  var url = require('url');
  var fs = require('fs');
  const hostname = '127.0.0.1';
  const port = 3000;
  http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  var q = url.parse(req.url, true);
  var filename = "example.html";
  fs.readFile(filename, function(err, data) {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
    res.write(data);
    return res.end();
  });
}).listen(port, hostname,()=>{
    console.log(`Server running at http://${hostname}:${port}/`);
});
```

So far I can access to `example.html` by going to `localhost:3000`, using the same computer.

But I want to use other device to connect to this `example.html`. So I thought it should be straight forward. First, I need to find out the `local IP`:

```
var os = require('os');
var addresses = [];
for (var k in interfaces) {
    for (var k2 in interfaces[k]) {
        var address = interfaces[k][k2];
        if (address.family === 'IPv4' && !address.internal) {
            addresses.push(address.address);
        }
    }
}
console.log(addresses);
```

I get `192.168.0.200`, which is the ip my wifi router provide to my computer. Then, I try access to `example.html` by browser with URL `192.168.0.200:3000`, The browser cannot find the page.

Is there anything missing?

Comment: Your app is listening on `127.0.0.1`

Comment: that is localhost, and sure you can access it using the same computer with that. however, if you want to use other device to access this, you need to find the IP that is provided by the wifi router, which is `192.168.0.200`. But somehow that did not work.

Comment: @tkausl actually, you are close to the answer. check my answer below:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turn out, it is rather straight forward.
I just have to replace `127.0.0.1` with whichever IP router provided.

```
///get the ip from the router
var os = require('os');
var addresses = [];
for (var k in interfaces) {
    for (var k2 in interfaces[k]) {
        var address = interfaces[k][k2];
        if (address.family === 'IPv4' && !address.internal) {
            addresses.push(address.address);
        }
    }
}
console.log(addresses);///<-- addresses is an array

 const http = require('http');
  var url = require('url');
  var fs = require('fs');
  const hostname = addresses[0];///<-- first element of addresses
  const port = 3000;
  http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  var q = url.parse(req.url, true);
  var filename = "example.html";
  fs.readFile(filename, function(err, data) {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
    res.write(data);
    return res.end();
  });
}).listen(port, hostname,()=>{
    console.log(`Server running at http://${hostname}:${port}/`);
});
```

then, you can do `192.168.0.200:3000/example.html` from any device.